# How to get image location with Sikuli using Java?

Tags: java, automation, ui-automation, sikuli

It's very hard to find Sikuli examples for Java, all is written for Python or Sikuli IDE. I have defined a pattern that I'm able to click on, hover etc..

How can I save its coordinates into a variable so I'll be able to use it later for navigation?

Comment: You sure can but it will help if you shared your code to better understand how you use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you mean when you say "pattern". Do you refer to the actual Sikuli `Pattern` class? Or just use it as general word? Anyway, you can store the coordinates of a pattern found on the screen like this:

```
Region reg = new Screen();
Pattern p = new Pattern("someImage.png");
Match m = reg.find(p);
```

Then you can either access the coordinates directly as they all defined using public access level modifiers:

```
int x = m.x;
int y = m.y;
```

Or you can use the getter methods available through the same class:

```
int x = m.getX();
int y = m.getY();
```

Alternatively, you can store the whole `Location` object for your future reference:

```
Location l = m.getTarget();

int x = l.x;
int y = l.y;

int x = l.getX();
int y = l.getY();
```